# .done is successful but showing empty data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Once the quantity dropdown button is selected, the price field would be changed accordingly. However, I keep on getting successful alert, but the data is showing an empty result.

I have tried using success instead of done but the result is the same. I have also removed datatype: json, still no changes.

```
$('#qty').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
          method: "GET",
          url: "someURLHERE", 
          data: { val: val},
          dataType: "html"
        })
          .done(function(data) {
              alert("Success" + data);
                $('#price').html(data);
                $('#price').trigger('change');
          }).fail(function()  {
                alert("Fail");
   })

});
```

Here is my model:

```
  public function getPrice($product_id, $quantity){
       $sql = "SELECT price FROM `price_table` where quantity = '".$quantity."' and product_id = '".$product_id."' ";
       $query = $this->db->query($sql)->row_array();
       return $query;
   }
```

And here is my controller:

```
public function getPrice(){
    $p_id = $_GET['p_id'];
    $qty = $_GET['qty_ag'];

    $price = $this->users_model->getPrice($prpduct_id, $quantity);
    json_ok($price);
}
```

Now, the alert box is returning: Success{"status":"OK","data":{"pv_value":"120.00"}}

All I want to get is the value 120.00

Comment: Is your server returning the correct payload?

Comment: Success or error depend on the HTTP status code of the response; whether that response actually has any body content does not matter in that regard. Go inspect the request in your browser dev tools, network panel, and check what gets actually returned.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? How is this related to PHP after all?

Comment: #price defined in which element?

Comment: because     $('#price').html(data); won't work if its a input tag

Comment: `console.log(data)` will show you the way.

Comment: I used console.log(data)  and it shows me status ok and returns the value but my alert message is not showing the correct data. When I changed return($price) to json_ok($price), it shows me [object Object] instead.

Comment: I've edited my codings. Please check on it.

Comment: Use `data.pv_value` in your callback

Answer (score 0):

You said you removed `dataType: "JSON"`, but what type of data you're returning in the server side (PHP), and also, how you're returning it?

**For example**

If you're expectating JSON type of data, then you can still using this in JavaScript:

```
$('#qty').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "someURLHERE", 
      data: {
        val: val
      },
      dataType: "JSON" // notice I've returned it to JSON
    })
    .done(function(data){
      console.log("Success" + data); // notice I'm using "console.log"
      $('#price').html(data);
      $('#price').trigger('change');
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert("Fail");
    })
});
```

But, in the server side, PHP should return data like this:

```
<?php
  header("Content-Type: application/json");
  die(json_encode($yourData));
?>
```

Comment: Your PHP script should have a text/json content-type header, otherwise that JSON is going to be served as HTML.

Comment: Well reminded this good practice, thanks! Edited and added, but, the correct use is "application/json".

Comment: do'h, I always make that mistake!

Comment: I have edited my question on the controller and model. My alert is still showing successful message anyway.

Comment: When I changed the return $price to json_ok($price), the data I got is [object Object]. What could I missed? Thank you so much!!

Comment: `alert("Success" + data);`  don't attempt to `alert` an object

Comment: Use `console.log(data)` so you should see your data into your browser dev tools console

Answer (score 0):

Your model `getPrice()` method must return something.

Comment: I've edited my coding. I'm pretty sure the issue is on my controller but I seem can't figure it out. Thank you for helping!!